# Photoshop Gradient Editor Is Missing Key Settings...Can No Longer Pick Gradient Type, Presets & Smoothness, Etc.

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, text

First, thank you for taking the time to look at this.

My gradient editor is missing key settings including: stops, presets, gradient type, name and smoothness settings.  It used to work just fine and then one day all of those settings disappeared and now I’m left with a gradient editor box that doesn’t allow me to edit anything. I apologize if I’m not using the correct terms, I’m a newbie. Please help!

[image: gradient editor]